# Does "divertere" ever meant "to have fun/entertain" in Latin?

Tags: meaning

According to Wiktionary, the Latin verb *[divertere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diverto#Latin)* means:

[image]

This meaning has been preserved in equivalent terms found in Latin-based or Latin-influenced languages like [French](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divertir#French), [Catalan](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divertir#Catalan), [Portuguese](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divertir#Portuguese), [Italian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divertire#Italian) and [English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divert#English). However, in all the above, this word also means "to entertain" or "to have fun". Amazingly, in [Spanish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divertir#Spanish) that is the only meaning it has!

It seems a rather odd coincidence that a term adopted by multiple languages from Latin ended up having a new and identical meaning. Perhaps, *divertere* also meant (and still means) "to have fun" in Latin. Yet, I cannot find evidence for this. Neither L&S nor the Vulgata record such meaning. Are you aware of this extra meaning of *divertere*? If not, how can we explain the coincidence in the derived terms?